# Передача данных сразу на все шаблоны django

Tags: python, django, django-template

Как передавать какие-нибудь данные сразу на все шаблоны django? Как, например, модель пользователя

Делаю интернет-магазин, и у меня появилась задача: Сделать так, чтобы **кол-во товаров в корзине или в избранном передавалась на все шаблоны**. Я думаю, вы знаете, как это работает.

И вот как мне это правильно реализовать на **Django**?

Я додумался до двух способов:

1. Первый - самый простой и неудобный - это вручную прописывать к каждому шаблону и если изменить скрипт получения кол-ва, то всё нужно будет изменять вручную.
2. Второй - добавить в модель пользователя дополнительные поля по типу quantity_products_in_cart...

Даже не знаю... Оба способа выглядят костылями, и я хочу узнать как правильно. **Буду очень благодарен за помощь**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напишите свой `middleware`, который будет пихать в `request` объект с вашими данными, например, корзину текущего пользователя.

```
class SimpleMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.

        request.basket = get_user_basket(request.user) # <==== вот так например

        response = self.get_response(request)

        # Code to be executed for each request/response after
        # the view is called.

        return response
```

Тогда в шаблоне корзина будет доступна в `request.basket`. Пример ниже

```
{% if request.basket %}
    {{ request.basket.count|default:0 }} 
{% endif %}
```

Пример и подробную информацию можно почитать на [оф.сайте документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/middleware/)

Comment: Большое спасибо! Узнаю побольше об этих middleware. А ведь надо было в документацию посмотреть... :)